# How debug specify class without modifying the class code?

Tags: c#, oop, debugging, architecture

I am c# developer , i want to insert code to a class without modfiy the original class in order to debug. i know some has post the question, bug his answers is not c# . anyone can tell me what to do ? sorry can't post image because of my less reputation.

Comment: Why do you want to insert code? Why not simply debug your code?

Comment: Just want not to modify my code every debug times.

Comment: @user4668159 To debug, do not modify your code. To debug, use a debugger, and add breakpoints to break and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to extend your code if you want to debug it, simply put a break point in the line you want to debug it then run your code and using Step Over button or Step Into if you need.

But if you want to extend your class without modify it, simply inhirate it and do your modifications also you can extend methods without changing it.